# Smooth parts of adjacent polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, smoothing

I have got a set of layers, for example, villages, districts and towns.
Their borders are the same on edges of town layer and need to be smooth. I used to perform it manually using topology edit tool. But is there something like advanced topolohy edit tool that can smooth selected lines in several layers.

I tried feature polygon to line and then smooth lines. But it is complicated to convert it back to polygons with original attributes.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Advanced?  If so when you converted your polygons to lines you could also convert them to points (inside polygon option selected) and then planarized your lines (to get rid of coincident lines) prior to smoothing.  Then you could build polygons using the points as attributes option. If you don't have advanced the foregoing is more complicated although you could try a spatial join to get the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If your layers reside in the same Geodatabase, you can build a topology that includes your layers. On the Topology Toolbar there is Generalize Edge tool, that will smooth edges in multiple layers at the same time. Please see the online help - "Editing shared geometry with topology"

Comment: I checked out that tool but it does the opposite thing, a kind of ordinary generalization. I haven't found any smooth features there///

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Integrate](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/integrate.htm) is the tool you are looking for?

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.